# MSDN: Conflicting subscription information. Am I subscribed?

Tags: visual-studio, msdn

I logged in to MSDN to check if I still had an active subscription. This is what it looks like in my subscriptions tab. It looks like I'm subscribed until 2016, but then the right side says no subscription. Any ideas?

[image: MSDN]

Comment: Just one idea - go talk to Microsoft. This is a question for their customer service team.

Answer (score 0):

Click the "*Help*" link at the top of the "*Account*" window.  This will take you to MSDN Subscriber Help.  In the left-side navigation pane of that window, choose "Contact Us".  That will take you to a contact page that lists all MSDN Subscriptions Customer Service Centers globally, along email and phone contact info.

Here is a direct link: [MSDN Subscriptions Customer Service Centers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/aa948875.aspx).